# Do both "stat -f" and "cat /etc/fstab" show file system ids?

Tags: linux, filesystems, stat

On Ubuntu 14.04, I am checking the filesystem for my home based on a file `new` in it:

```
$ stat -f new
  File: "new"
    ID: 38d4cd29e44142c6 Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 144152970  Free: 79424314   Available: 72095994
Inodes: Total: 36626432   Free: 35430143
```

I am also checking it by another way:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=8620616e-3745-420e-9082-c6f9df5b0f15 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=bcd7575f-97d7-47f8-951a-83675195061c /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=aba3f8f2-9a25-4ef3-96ba-c12b40622eca none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**Added**: another way:

```
$ stat  new
  File: ‘new’
  Size: 928         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 28188755    Links: 1
Access: (0622/-rw--w--w-)  Uid: ( 1000/       t)   Gid: ( 1000/       t)
Access: 2015-12-19 06:33:07.842559147 -0500
Modify: 2013-06-11 12:54:44.944836000 -0400
Change: 2015-03-25 11:15:20.778708140 -0400
 Birth: -
```

1. What does `ID` mean in the out put of `stat -f`? Is it the
   filesystem ID of the filesystem in my home partition?

   What does it depend on? Not on the mount point?
2. What does the first column in `/etc/fstab`? is it the filesystem ID
   of each filesystem?
3. What are the differences between the two kinds of ID given by the
   two ways?
4. why does `stat -f` show the file system type is `ext2/ext3` while my home filesystem type is ext4?
5. **Added:** what does `Device` mean in the output of `stat` without `-f`? Is it an id of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to `man stat` the ID is the ID of the filesystem, whatever that may or may not mean. I'm guessing this is generated when the filesystem is.
2. The first column references the partition UUID, *not* the filesystem ID. It's a departure from the more traditional `/dev/sdXX`, mostly because with modern systems it's sometimes possible for the traditional drive order to be shuffled around in the BIOS, but the UUID will remain the same.
3. As 1) and 2) point out, they're different IDs denoting entirely different aspects. They're roughly as related as your Social Security Number and your home address in that they're both associated with you, but that's it.
4. Because `ext4` is an extension to `ext3` which is an extension to `ext2`. The part of the signature that `stat` looks at is the same in each case, hence the identification.
5. Again, according to `man stat`, when you omit '-f' stat looks at the file itself rather than the filesystem it's on, and the value after 'Device' is the hex-and-decimal value of the filesystem's device ID. I should probably also point out that with `stat -f` you did not in fact get the information about the filesystem you wanted to get information about.

**Yes, but what does this all mean?**

A **UUID** is assigned by the partition manager when you create the partition. You can change it manually if you want but there's almost never a reason to and generally every reason *not* to. Modern linux systems prefer to use the UUID rather than the device number to determine what is mounted where, just in case new hardware is added which changes the device letter ordering. See [here](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/uuids-and-linux-everything-you-ever-need-to-know/) for more information about UUIDs.

A **device id** is the combination of major and minor number that identifies that particular block device. In your case, '804' identifies the fourth partition of the first SCSI-like drive located according to the BIOS. In traditional terms, this would be `/dev/sda4`.

They are two different ways of identifying the same thing, via different methods -- `/dev/sda4` will always point to the fourth partition on the first SCSI-like device, which can fail spectacularly if you add another hard drive to your system and for some reason the BIOS identifies it first; `UUID=8620616e-3745-420e-9082-c6f9df5b0f15` refers to the partition in your system with that unique identifier, regardless of how your devices are shifted around internally.

Comment: Thanks. In 4, what does signature mean? I still don't understand why stat doesn't show ext4 as type.

Comment: Is filesystem id inherent to a filesystem? Is partition uuid inherent to a partition?

Comment: what does `Device` mean in the output of `stat` without `-f`? Is it an id of something?

Comment: Is `Device` the id of a partition not of a device? (I have several partitions in the same device, and `Device` is different for files in different partitions). If yes, why is `Device` not the same as the partition UUID in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Because it's another way of describing the device node.

Comment: How do you know " '804' identifies the fourth partition of the first SCSI-like drive located. In traditional terms, this would be /dev/sda4."?

Comment: *because I looked it up*. Major number 8 denotes the first SCSI-like block device; minor number 4 means the fourth partition on that device.

Comment: Thanks. (1) where did you look it up? (2) If the device id is made up of major and minor numbers of a partition, do `stat -c "%t%T"` also give the major and minor numbers of a partition? If yes, why are the two ways give different major and minor numbers?

Comment: 1) Google is your friend. 2) It does, and it's actually the same number -- major number 8, minor number 4, '0804' when spelled in hexadecimal because hex is properly written in byte form, because 215 is less than 39.

Comment: (1) What keyword can I search for? (2) `stat -c "%t%T" new` outputs `00`, which is neither major or minor numbers of a partition from `Device` in `stat new`. So it is not right that "it's actually the same number".

Comment: It *is*, because you asked it for the major/minor numbers of the file `new` -- which doesn't have either because it's not a block device. The information under 'device' when you run `stat new` refers to the major/minor of the block device the file is located on.

Comment: Google tips: "Linux devices major minor number" "linux GNU stat meaning" "linux device UUID" and so on and so on.

Comment: Thanks. In 4, what does signature mean? I still don't understand why stat doesn't show ext4 as type.

Comment: Not relevant since, as I already pointed out, you were literally *looking at the wrong thing*.